# Edit a chrome notification after it was called?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

my chrome extension uses notifications. I am calling them with:

```
function notifyMe(message) {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('No desktop notifications possible!'); 
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification('Bot success!', {
      icon: 'https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_9/0Bx4BSt6jniD7blViQzF0azNqZU0/style_icons_system_intro_principles_consistent.png',
      body: message,
    });

    setTimeout(function() { notification.close() }, 5000);

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("http://google.com");      
    };

  }

}

notifyMe("I am a notification!");
```

Is there a way to change message , icon and title when the notification is already there? And is there a way to close it down from another function instead of the 5000ms timeout inside the function itself?

I tried a few things about closing it from the outside by defining *var notification*; at the beginning of my script to allow access from everywhere, but this didn't work too well.

This might be pretty obvious, but I am still kind of new to JS. Sorry for that!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are creating a notification using a (web) [`Notification` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API), not the extension specific [`chrome.notifications` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).** With that in mind:

> And is there a way to close it down from another function instead of the 5000ms timeout inside the function itself?

As long as you store the `notification` object returned by the constructor, you can call `notification.close()` at any point.

> I tried a few things about closing it from the outside by defining var notification; at the beginning of my script to allow access from everywhere, but this didn't work too well.

This is a valid strategy; but if you write `var notification` again inside your function, you no longer access the global `notification` variable but create a new local one with the same name. If you have a global variable, avoid adding `var` anywhere else.

Might want to check out [You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures) if you're interested in a deeper look at how scope works in JS

> Is there a way to change message, icon and title when the notification is already there?

You cannot edit an existing notification created by Notifications API - all of its properties are read-only after creation, and it does not prove an update method.

Instead, however, you can [*replace* a notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Replacing_existing_notifications) if you create a new one with the same [`tag` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/tag):

```
new Notification('One', {
  tag: "replaceMe"
});
new Notification('Two', {
  tag: "replaceMe"
});
// Will result in only one notification, "Two", being shown
```

---

Consider using [`chrome.notifications` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) for your purposes. It offers a few more features over `Notifications` API, such as buttons (at least, in Chrome - less of an advantage if you want a shared codebase with Firefox), and doesn't require a runtime permission request.

Answer (score 0):

You can update a Chrome notification using [chrome.notifications.update](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#method-update)

Comment: Except this is not a notification created by `chrome.notifications`.